# print full item in multiple lists

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to print two lists, but it only prints the first letter of each item in the lists;

```
lst1 = ['hello', 'hi', 'sup']
lst2 = ['bye', 'cya', 'goodbye']

for item in [lst1, lst2]:
    print 'Your options are: ' + ' '.join(['-{0}'.format(*x) for x in item])
```

Result;

```
You can choose: -h -h -s
You can choose: -b -c -g
```

How do I print the string in full?

Comment: Why'd you use `.format(*x)`?

Comment: what do you think this `format(*x)` does ?

Comment: Remove the `*` in front of `x`. The star unpack the string into a list of chars.

Comment: Maybe [`print 'Your options are: -' + ' -'.join(item)`](http://ideone.com/OdWDql)? What is your expected result?

Comment: @njzk2 sorry, got mixed up with unpacking tuples for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `*` from `format` will work for you:

```
>>> for item in [lst1, lst2]:
...     print 'Your options are: ' + ' '.join(['-{0}'.format(x) for x in item])
... 
Your options are: -hello -hi -sup
Your options are: -bye -cya -goodbye
```

**Explaination**: `*my_list` unpacks the list. Since, string is also a `list` of `chars`, `'-{0}'.format(*x)` will become: `'-{0}'.format(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])`. Hence, it is just inserting the string at the 0th index of `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']` i.e. `h`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative;

```
>>> print '\n'.join('Your options are: -%s' % ' -'.join(x) for x in (lst1, lst2))
Your options are: -hello -hi -sup
Your options are: -bye -cya -goodbye
```

#### How it works

To generate a line of output:

```
>>> 'Your options are: -%s' % ' -'.join(lst1)
'Your options are: -hello -hi -sup'
```

To generate the complete output, the above is done for both `lst1` and `lst2` and combined with `'\n'.join(...)`.